# How to create a view from an other one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

In postgreSQL, I created a table `my_table`:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS roipoussiere cascade;
CREATE SCHEMA roipoussiere;

CREATE TABLE roipoussiere.my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  x smallint,
  y smallint);

INSERT INTO roipoussiere.my_table(x, y) VALUES (42, 42);
-- [etc.]
```

... from which I created views `view_a` and `view_b`, that have both the same columns (but different content):

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS roipoussiere.view_a CASCADE;
CREATE VIEW roipoussiere.view_a AS SELECT
  concat_ws('view_a_', x, '_', y) AS foo,
  'Hello' AS bar,
  x,
  y
FROM roipoussiere.my_table;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS roipoussiere.view_b CASCADE;
CREATE VIEW roipoussiere.view_b AS SELECT
  concat_ws('view_b_', x, '_', y) AS foo,
  'Hello' AS bar,
  x,
  y
FROM roipoussiere.my_table;
```

... then I created the view `my_view`, union of `view_a` and `view_b` :

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS roipoussiere.my_view CASCADE;
CREATE VIEW roipoussiere.my_view AS
  SELECT * FROM roipoussiere.view_a UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM roipoussiere.view_b;
```

But `view_a` and `view_b` have a lot of content in common, just some columns are differents. So I would like to avoid redundancy and create `view_a`, then create `view_b` *from* `view_a` (ie, without creating column `bar` twice, which is identical for all views).

Note: it is a simplified example, in practice:

- there are 4 views, not 2;
- there are few other columns like `foo` ;
- tens of other columns like `bar` (with hard-coded data) on each view.

Comment: Are you looking for `create view view_b as select ... from view_a`?

Comment: Inside `...`, I need to write all the column names?

Comment: If you don't want to write all column names use `select *`

Comment: Like `CREATE VIEW view_a AS select * FROM view_a; ALTER TABLE view_b ALTER COLUMN foo SET concat_ws('view_a_', x, '_', y)` ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, fyi the `CAST('text' AS TEXT)` was useful because without it I get the error *could not determine the collation to use for the column "target_name"*, I remember now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You aren't "Creating a column" like what you think in a view. A view doesn't hold any data, it's just a definition of a way you "View" the data in the underlying table that the view references.
2. You are suggesting that you ALTER the underlying table to match your VIEW B, but if you do that then the results that come in View A will be changed.
3. You are already combining your views in your UNION. Instead of referencing the views by name, you can reference them directly by the SQL you used to define the view. It's all the same.

So, in one query:

```
Create VIEW roipoussiere.view_c AS
SELECT
  concat_ws('view_a_', x, '_', y) AS foo,
  'Hello' AS bar,
  x,
  y
FROM roipoussiere.my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT
  concat_ws('view_b_', x, '_', y) AS foo,
  'Hello' AS bar,
  x,
  y
FROM roipoussiere.my_table;
```

Any time you find yourself creating views on top of views (on top of views on top of views) ask yourself if you really need those underlying views on their own. Will you ever execute ViewA by itself, or is it just there to make View C easier to write? If you don't need it, then don't make it, just do the SELECT in a subquery in the final view.

To get out of writing `'Hello' as bar` and your other constant-type fields over and over again each of your SELECT statements that are union'd together, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to define it once in your 1 view and use it over and over again.

```
CREATE VIEW roipoussiere.view_c as
WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT

      'Hello' AS bar,
      'Goodbye' as f1,
      'Another constant' as f2
      x,
      y
    FROM roipoussiere.my_table
)
SELECT
  concat_ws('view_a_', x, '_', y) AS foo,
  bar,
  f1,
  f2,
  x,
  y
FROM myCTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
  concat_ws('view_b_', x, '_', y) AS foo,
  bar,
  f1,
  f2,
  x,
  y
FROM myCTE
```

Comment: So `'Hello' AS bar` is repeated, is there any way to don't repeat it?

Comment: Do you need it on that record? Are you afraid of repeat code, or repeat data? Your code is dictated by your requirements. If you need 'Hello' to show up on a record with that concatenated 'view_b' stuff, then you will have to add that as a field in your SELECT. Perhaps share your desired results in your question and we can help build sql to achieve that. I still get the sense that you are confusing what a view does, but perhaps I'm just reading your question incorrectly.

Comment: I afraid to repeat 'Hello', because there are a lot of data like this and if someone want to change one of them, I want to be sure the other views will get the same data.

Comment: Oh, maybe I can create `view_template` with `Hello` inside, then create `view_a` and `view_b` from `view_template`?

Comment: Sure, or instead of creating another view, you could use a CTE. That would cut down on superfluous views and give you the ability to only identify your fields that are constants without repeating code.

Comment: I don't really knows CTE but I think it's what I am looking for. Could you post it as an answer (or edit yours)?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example using a CTE. I have a feeling that it will solve the problem you are trying to solve. CTE's are super nice for consolidating code where you are finding yourself writing the same thing over and over and over again in a subquery. The nice thing with the CTE is that if you want to change `foo` to read `Hi` instead of `Hello` you only need to change it one spot.